# Error on backup bash script: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: bash, backup

I am having problem finding error on bash script for handling backup:daily, monthly, yearly. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo > /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt
#writing dates of the backups that should be kept to the array

for i in {0..7}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-$i day")]++)); done
for i in {0..4}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$((i+1)) week")]++)); done
for i in {0..12}; do
        DW=$(($(date +%-W)-$(date -d $(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y-%m-01) +%-W)))
        for (( AY=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do
        ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)))
        done
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++))
done
for i in {0..30}; do
        DW=$(date +%-W)
        for (( AY=$(($(date +%Y)-i)); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do
        ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)))
        done
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++))
        done

#writing the array to file keep.txt line by line
for i in ${!keep[@]}; do echo $i >> /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt; done

#delete all files that not mentioned in keep.txt
cd /home/alpha/folder
ls -1 /home/alpha/folder/ | sort /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt - | uniq -u | xargs rm -rf
rm /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt
```

When I try to run the script, throws error message:

```
./back.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' ./back.sh: line 12: ` done'
```

Where did I do wrong on the script?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with helpful link maybe.

Comment: Sorry, it was an error on my part when testing the script, I removed the comment

Comment: Bunch of issues involving not double quoting the variables, copy paste your script under http://www.shellcheck.net/ and see it for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date` expression seems to misbehave inside the arithmetic context. Adding temporary variables solved your issue for me :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo > /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt
#writing dates of the backups that should be kept to the array

for i in {0..7}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-$i day")]++)); done
for i in {0..4}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$((i+1)) week")]++)); done
for i in {0..12}; do
        DW=$(($(date +%-W)-$(date -d $(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y-%m-01) +%-W)))
        begin=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y)
        for (( AY=begin; AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do
        ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)))
        done
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++))
done
for i in {0..30}; do
        DW=$(date +%-W)
        begin=$(($(date +%Y)-i))
        for (( AY=begin; AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do
        ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)))
        done
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++))
        done

#writing the array to file keep.txt line by line
for i in ${!keep[@]}; do echo $i >> /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt; done

#delete all files that not mentioned in keep.txt
cd /home/alpha/folder
ls -1 /home/alpha/folder/ | sort /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt - | uniq -u | xargs rm -rf
rm /home/alpha/folder/keep.txt
```

However, I am unsure why the expression misbehaves inside the arithmetic block.

Comment: Array expansions should be double-quoted, `for i in "${!keep[@]}"`

Comment: @Inian I know this is best practice, however this doesn't affect the issue OP has. For this answer, I just copied/pasted OP's code along with my suggestions. He can refer to the shellcheck link you posted in the comments to improve his code further. As a side note, as the values stored in the array are timestamp, quotation most likely won't have any effect on the results.